# How to fix "too few arguments to function mkdir"

Tags: c

Im a coding noob. I have to compile some codes for my project in a HPC server. I can compile the codes in my laptop but when i run it on the HPC i get the error message

> "too few arguments to function mkdir".

I have tried to print the output in the cwd and not in the output directory but it still didnt fix the problem. If i use the check command declared as a comment (which one of my instructors advised), I get the error check undeclared first use in the function.

```
void write_collection_pvd(int time_total, int time_save, char *directory, char *filename)
{
    int x;
    char dataFileName[255];
    FILE *dataFile;
    //#ifdef WIN32
    mkdir(directory);
    //#else
      //  check = mkdir(directory,0777);
    //#endif
    sprintf(dataFileName, "%s/%s.pvd", directory, filename);
}
```

i expect the pvd file to be written in the ouput directory. Thanks in advance`enter code here`

Comment: "when i run it on the HPC i get the error message" - do you get this error during _runtime_ or when compiling? The first option looks unlikely

Comment: Please read the docs for the functions you're calling. "not enough arguments to function" is a pretty big hint.

Comment: @ForceBru I get this error when compiling

Comment: @AdhithyaGovindan, on Linux, `mkdir` [accepts two arguments](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir).

Comment: If something complains about "To few arguments", maybe you should add more? :)

Answer (score 0):

In C, the `mkdir` function accepts *two* parameters: the name of the directory to create and the (typically octal) permission mode to give it.  So instead of calling

```
mkdir(directory);
```

you should call something like

```
mkdir(directory, 0777);
```

That will give the new directory permissions of read, write, and search (execute) by the owner, group, and everybody else.  But (at least under Unix and Linux) these permissions will be adjusted downward by your process's default permissions, which will typically turn off writability by world and often group.

Comment: Thanks. This was the first thing i tried. The compiler does not show any error but does not produce any output either

Comment: @AdhithyaGovindan When you say *"the compiler ... does not produce any output"*, do you mean it doesn't print anything to the console or that it doesn't create an executable file?

Comment: @AdhithyaGovindan So there are two more things to do: (1) print out the value of your `check` variable.  If it's 0 it's trying to tell you that `mkdir` succeeded, but if it's -1 that means `mkdir` failed. (2) If it returns -1, additionally call `perror("mkdir")` or for extra credit `fprintf(stderr, "can't make directory %s: %s\n", directory, strerror(errno));`. (For the latter you'll need to include `<string.h>` and `<errno.h>`.)